# Error When Trying To Add A Variable In A Php Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Can someone show me how to correct this query that keeps giving me sql syntax error ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browsing_histories.php:38 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browsing_histories.php(38): mysqli->query('SELECT
>   * FROM b...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\browsing_histories.php on line 38

I need to do this so that, I do not have to write hundreds of queries but one. Hundreds of queries where each is for each column queries. Eg.

```
$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE USERNAME = ? ")->num_rows; 

$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE FIRST_NAME = ? ")->num_rows; 

$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE GENDER = ? ")->num_rows; 

$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE AGE-RANGE = ? ")->num_rows;
```

And so on ...

One query should do it like we can with non-prepared statements. Hence, did it like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE $query_type = ? 
ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?');
```

Full Context:

```
$query_type = $_GET['query_type']; 

//If $_GET['query_type']) is empty then show error as it must be set. 
if(!isset($_GET['query_type']) && empty($_GET['query_type'])) 
{ 
    echo "Invalid Query!"; 
} 
//If $_GET['query_type']) is full with value other than wild-card or "All" 
or "all" then make speccific query. 
elseif($query_type != 'all' OR $query_type != 'All' OR $query_type != '*') 
{ 
    ${$query_type} = $_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 
    $followed_word = ${$query_type}; //Same as: $_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 

    $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
$query_type = ?")->num_rows; 
    //Make the query. 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
$query_type = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $query_type, $calc_page, $num_results_on_page); 
} 
else //Make general query or query for all records. 
{ 
    //Grab "all records" from the table. 
    //Get the total number of records from the table: 
"browsing_histories". 
    $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories")- 
>num_rows; 
    //Make the query. 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories ORDER BY id 
LIMIT ?,?'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $num_results_on_page); 
} 

$stmt->execute();
```

NOTE: Even when I change the $query_type in the prepared statement query to an actual column name such as "username" then I still get the same error.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE username = 
? 
ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?');
```

EDIT 1:
Fixed my code to following but no luck!

```
$query_type = $_GET['query_type']; 

//If $_GET['query_type']) is empty then show error as it must be set. 
if(!isset($_GET['query_type']) && empty($_GET['query_type'])) 
{ 
    echo "Invalid Query!"; 
} 
//If $_GET['query_type']) is full with value other than wild-card or 
"All" or "all" then make speccific query. 
elseif($query_type != 'all' OR $query_type != 'All' OR $query_type != 
'*') 
{ 
    ${$query_type} = $_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 
    $followed_word = ${$query_type}; //Same as: 
$_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 

    $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
username = ?")->num_rows; 
    //Make the query. 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
username = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $query_type, $calc_page, 
$num_results_on_page); 
} 
else //Make general query or query for all records. 
{ 
    //Grab "all records" from the table. 
    //Get the total number of records from the table: 
"browsing_histories". 
    $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories")- 
>num_rows; 
    //Make the query. 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories ORDER BY id 
LIMIT ?,?'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $calc_page, $num_results_on_page); 
} 

$stmt->execute();
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my latest update. Problem remains. The commented-out queries are the ones that I experimented with. All of them show error the same one.
The non-commented-out one shows error too.

```
    $query_type = $_GET['query_type']; 

    //If $_GET['query_type']) is empty then show error as it must be set. 
    if(!isset($_GET['query_type']) && empty($_GET['query_type'])) 
    { 
        echo "Invalid Query!"; 
    } 
    //If $_GET['query_type']) is full with value other than wild-card or 
    "All" or "all" then make speccific query. 
    elseif($query_type != 'all' OR $query_type != 'All' OR $query_type != 
    '*') 
    { 
    ${$query_type} = $_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 
    $followed_word = ${$query_type}; //Same as: 
    $_GET[$_GET['query_type']]; 

    //$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    ? = ?")->num_rows; 
    //$total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    \"$query_type\" = ?")->num_rows; 
    $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    $query_type = ?")->num_rows; 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', ${$query_type}); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    //Make the query. 
    //$stmt_2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE ? 
    = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?"); 
    //$stmt_2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    \"$query_type\" = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?"); 
    //$stmt_2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    $query_type = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?"); 
    $stmt_2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
    username = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?"); 

    //$stmt_2->bind_param('sii', $query_type, ${$query_type}, $calc_page, 
    $num_results_on_page); 
    $stmt_2->bind_param('sii', ${$query_type}, $calc_page, 
    $num_results_on_page); 
    } 
    else //Make general query or query for all records. 
    { 
        //Grab "all records" from the table. 
        //Get the total number of records from the table: 
        "browsing_histories". 
        $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories")- 
        >num_rows; 
        //Make the query. 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories ORDER BY 
        id LIMIT ?,?'); 
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $calc_page, $num_results_on_page); 
        } 

        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

two param  need  two values

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $num_results_on_page, $second_value);
```

and for this 3 param 3 values

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE username = ? 
ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?'); 

$stmt->bind_param('sii',$your_username_value, $num_results_on_page, $second_value);
```

and check the code for

```
 $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE username = ?")->num_rows;
```

seems without param too

Comment: ScaisEdge,

I have added an "Edit 1" in my original post updating the script to your suggestion. But no luck.

Comment: check the  code for ` $total_pages = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE 
username = ?")->num_rows; `   seems without param too

Comment: I have checked. The error says problem is in this line:

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM browsing_histories WHERE username = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,?");

Seems like it doesn't like:
"WHERE username = ?".

Comment: My updated code is in EDIT 2. All these experiments too you see on EDIT 2 also failed. Problem with the same error regarding query syntax error remains.
Original tutorial code which I modified is here:
https://codeshack.io/how-to-create-pagination-php-mysql/
Is this tutorial buggy ? I am a php beginner and programming beginner at that.

Comment: It is the 2nd query that shows the error. 1st query queries the record count. The 2nd query queries the db for results. Error always point to the 2nd query no matter how many different ways I code the 2nd query. I tried all the following and I get the same error mentioned in my original post.

Check all the variety of stmt_2 (2nd queries) I tried. Check "Edit 2" in my original post.

Thanks a bunch for attempting to solve my issue!

Comment: I answered you above.

Thanks!

Comment: Two suggestion  .. first try execute the query without using param .. second are you sure the param contain valid value  .. id don't see the code where you assign valid value to these var

Comment: If you really must know I am a beginner in php and not even an intermediate. Only know procedural style programming and procedural style prepared statements. This code I showed on my original post is from a tutorial teaching how to build a pagination page in oop style. Problem is, I do not know oop style and this tutorial only shows how to build pagination that displays all results from the tbl. No search feature. I am trying to build the search feature so only relevant results get displayed in the pagination pages.

Comment: I'm struggling to fix this code I got the from the tutorial as it is in oop style. Hence, need your expert help where you show me a sample code how it should be so I can learn from you. I started learning oop style yesterday. Started learning pdo from pdodelusions.com. So, how about showing me an example how it should have been so I can count your sample as my tutorial snippet ? How-about filling in the missing puzzles for me so I can learn from your code and quicken learning oop style ?

Thanks